# Request Dinâmico entre ambiente de desenvolvimento e Produção

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de saber como resolver o problema de request entre um ambiente local e de produção.

Exemplo:

tenho uma função JS que pega o contexo da aplicação e concatena com o request.

```
var ctx = window.location.pathname.substring(0, window.location.pathname.indexOf("/",2));

ctx+'/Portal/listaProdutos'
```

Localmente ficaria: ***localhost:8080/"nomedaaplicação"/Portal/listaProdutos***

Porém em produção, os requests estão pegando o contexto duplicado: www.nomedosite.com/Portal/Portal/listaProdutos.

Como resolver esse problema?

Outra dica:

Também tenho request assim: `ctx+'/carregaBarSearch'`, sendo que estou navegando em paginas com o contexto `/Portal` , `www.nomedosite.com/Portal/Home`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve definir um dns ou ip estático para os seus servidores e definir como path base das suas requisições.

Comment: Opa,na real eu apenas preciso saber como ficaria o contexto dinâmico em JS.

Comment: Cara na minha concepção, você deve definir uma variavel global e em determinado mometo usar um ajax para pegar essa informação do servidor. talvez fosse a forma mais certa.. mas dai entra a questão q vc nao tem o endereço do servidor pra usar pra fazer um ajax. Então acho que nesse caso teria que ser manualmente.